# Solution of Maxwell's equations in curved spacetime

Tags: electromagnetism, general-relativity, spacetime, resource-recommendations, maxwell-equations

Can someone please suggest some resources on the topic of the solution of [Maxwell's equations in curved spacetime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell%27s_equations_in_curved_spacetime)?

I have already read about Maxwell's equation in curved spacetime from the book of Carmeli and Malin Theory of spinors-An introduction but I have to study about the solution of those equations. Please suggest some resources

Comment: It's pretty much all here, when you follow the related links. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_descriptions_of_the_electromagnetic_field.  If you list what you have gone through, and add the specific recommendations tag, that might help avoid duplication of effort.

Comment: @Countto10 But does this wiki contain the derivation of the solution of Maxwell's equation in curved spacetime?